# Calculate the distance between two triangulated surface meshes by CGAL

Tags: cgal, aabb

We need a tool to compute the distance between two triangulated surface meshes. And we are only allowed to use the CGAL to solve the problem.

I only found the API computing the distance from a point to a surface in `AABB tree` package, and some relevant APIs in `Surface_mesh_shortest_path` package. But I still can't fix my problem. Is there any tool in CGAL could fix my problem? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You posted that as an issue and we converted it into a [discussion](https://github.com/CGAL/cgal/discussions/7024), and told you that there is the [Hausdorff distance function](https://doc.cgal.org/latest/Polygon_mesh_processing/index.html#PMPDistance) in the Polygon Mesh Processing package. You did not react, so what is wrong about this answer?

Comment: Is there any way to calculate the minimum distance between the two meshes? Something like the `Extrema_ExtSS` in OCC